# CSS3: How do I make a linear gradient on top of an image suitable for cross browser compatibility?

Tags: css, background-image

My issue is caused by having a background gradient on top of an image.

How do I add the other properties e.g. -webkit, -o, to make it work in other browsers

```
div{
background:
linear-gradient(
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
),
url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg');

}
```

http://jsbin.com/rovini/1/edit?html,css,output

EDIT

If I add the vendor prefixes like so:

```
div{
background:
-mox-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
-webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
-o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg');
}
```

It does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yf7oL64e/)**

```
div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,.2)), to(rgba(0,0,0,.8))),url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg'); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg'); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg'); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg'); /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg'); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.8)),url('http://www.nhm.ac.uk/resources-rx/images/1007/women-artists-peach-banner_128346_2.jpg'); /* W3C */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)); /*Standard*/
}
```

You can see full examples from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp). Just remember to put the standard syntax last.

Answer (score 0):

### Original answer

What you need are called [vendor prefixes](http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/vendor-prefixes/). These allow support for css3 features which are not yet applied in general accross the browsers.

the simple syntax is: `-prefix` followed by `-property-name`
in your case it will be:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(...)
-moz-linear-gradient(...)
-ms-linear-gradient(...)
-o-linear-gradient(...)
linear-gradient(...)
```

`webkit` is for safari and chrome, `moz` for firefox, `ms` for IE and `o` for opera. But recently, `webkit`. The final one, without any prefix is for the possibility that the feature gets cross-platform support in future.

---

### Added after 1st comment

you need to put them with along with other css rules for the dom  element, ie, if you are writing css for a `div` with id papaya:

```
div#papaya{
    color: ...;
    font-size: ...;
    -webkit-linear-gradient(...);
       -moz-linear-gradient(...);
        -ms-linear-gradient(...);
         -o-linear-gradient(...);
            linear-gradient(...);
    /*any other properties*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my problem is where to put them

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shorthand way of grouping multiple background properties:

```
background: url('cats.jpg'), #000000;
```

which equates to

```
background-image: url('cats.jpg');
background-color: #000000;
```

What I wrote originally did not work because the browser looked at the 'background' property and couldn't understand the values I had used (the vendor prefixes).

Unfortunately, because I was stacking a gradient over an image, the vendor prefixes could not all be included in one reference to background. So, like Vlada903 said, the vendor prefixes need to be in their own reference to background so the browser can scan each, before finding the one it is able to understand and use.